# Using spherical coords to evaluate triple integral for the volume of the solid that lies under the paraboloid $z=4-x^2-y^2$ and above the xy-plane.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, spherical-coordinates

I'm having some trouble with the setup for this one.

I tried  $\int^{2\pi}_0\int^{\pi/2}_0\int^2_0\rho^2sin(\phi)d\rho d\phi d\theta$ , and got $\frac{16\pi}{3}$, confirmed in symbolab. but I seen that since I just have a z and not $z^2$ I can't get $\rho$ the way I was thinking. Some one else gave me $0<=\rho<=cos(\phi)$, and $\pi/4$ for $\phi$. So I set it up as

$2\pi \int _0^{\frac{\pi }{4}}\:\int _0^{cos\left(\theta \right)}\:p^2sin\left(\theta \right)dp\:d\theta $

And then checked again in symbolab before trying going through the eval. But that gave me $\pi/8$, where the answer should be $8\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
z=4-x^2-y^2\quad \Rightarrow \quad \rho\cos\phi = 4- \rho^2\sin^2\phi
$$
Solving for $\rho \ge 0$ yields
$$
\rho = \frac{-\cos\phi+\sqrt{1+15\sin^2\phi}}{2\sin^2\phi}
$$
So the bounds are
$$
0 \le \theta \le 2\pi, \quad 0 \le \rho \le \frac{-\cos\phi+\sqrt{1+15\sin^2\phi}}{2\sin^2\phi}, \quad 0 \le \phi \le \frac{\pi}{2}
$$
You can verify that
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\frac{-\cos\phi+\sqrt{1+15\sin^2\phi}}{2\sin^2\phi}} \rho^2\sin\phi\; d\rho d\phi d\theta = 8\pi
$$

**Note** The final computation is not trivial. If you have the choice, you are better of with cylindrical coordinates.